# How to configure phpMyAdmin on Nginx (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I configured Nginx successfully on my Ubuntu system.

And also installed PHP and phpMyAdmin successfully . But when I try to open the phpMyAdmin login panel it returns **403 Forbidden**

My Nginx server configuration looks like this

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location = /phpmyadmin/ {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    }

    location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }


    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I configured the phpMyAdmin part like this

```
location = /phpmyadmin/ {
        root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
    }
```

Can any one help me with the settings?

Answer (score 1):

1- `403` error must trigger you that the file you are accessing does not have proper permission, give it that. Check the error log(you need to switch `error_log on` if not already) to find out which files are being accessed and raising error.

2- define `index.php` as one of your `index` files.

3- add `try_files` directive in the `location` block for index.php.

4- Try to remove trailing `/` from phpmyadmin location, just like that.

Try below code,

```
server {
   ...
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   ...
   location ~ /phpmyadmin {
      root /usr/share/phpmyadmin/;
      try_files $uri /index.php; 
   }
}
```

*the above code is not tested, try to check the error log in case of any error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right  setting

# You may add here your
    # server {
    #   ...
    # }
    # statements for each of your virtual hosts to this file

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }


    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    #error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #

    location /phpmyadmin {
               root /usr/share/;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;
               location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                       try_files $uri =404;
                       root /usr/share/;
                       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; # or 127.0.0.1:9000
                       fastcgi_index index.php;
                       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                       include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
               }
               location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /usr/share/;
               }
        }
        location /phpMyAdmin {
               rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
        }

    location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#   listen 443;
#   server_name localhost;
#
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   ssl on;
#   ssl_certificate cert.pem;
#   ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
#
#   ssl_session_timeout 5m;
#
#   ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#   ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
#   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```